# How to install Qt5.12.11 without an account?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-installer

I downloaded the .exe installer from download.qt.io but it asks me to login to continue to install. I recall there is a skip button on the installation window to bypass the login in the past Qt releases. Does not Qt 5.12.11 allow to install without an account?  I disconnect the network connection but the skip button never appears.

B.T.W, more and more software/website require you to register to use their service. Is there some philosophy behind this trend? At the first glance, this policy creates inconvenience thus  reduces potential users.

Comment: The "Skip" button existed until February 2020, when logging in was required again (https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-offering-changes-2020). As of today, there is no way to download pre-built binaries from the official installer without logging in. You can, however, build Qt from source code (https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git) or use an unofficial installer (https://github.com/miurahr/aqtinstall), both without logging in.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It is a pity that the skip button is retired. I think many people will have to build qt themselves.

Comment: I noticed on https://www.qt.io/offline-installers there is only an offline installer for Qt 5 but not Qt 6 (which was released 1 year ago today)...
Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1140788/qt-install-offline

Comment: I have also downloaded official 5.12 offline installer and it asked me to login. I turned my airplane mode on and closed the qt installer window. Then reopen the window, a message poped up, that network configuration is missing or something. However next button was available which allowed me to install without internet connectivity.

Answer (score 8):

In case of an offline installer, you can just change the system time year to 2019, run the installer, press the button and roll the system time back.

Answer (score 7):

You could dowload the offline installer, the online installer require a qt account. Offline installer [link](https://www.qt.io/offline-installers).

First you should download and install the qt creator and then download and install the qt source package, if you do not want to use the qt-creator then you do not have to dowload that.

Comment: I downloaded the offline installer "Qt 5.12.11 for Linux 64-bit (1.3 GB)" and like someone said in comments, logging in is required. Even for the offline installer unfortunately but maybe there is a way to bypass the login form since the data is already downloaded for the "offline installer". If I disable my Internet connection and start the installer, it says "Network connection not found. If you are using proxy,
please modify proxy settings from 'Settings' or continue without internet connection." but we cannot continue. Even the FAQ is not up-to-date: https://wiki.qt.io/Ifw_FAQ

Comment: @baptx Just change the system time year to 2019, run the installer, press the button and roll the system time back.

Comment: @Andry you should create an answer with this comment as this is the only way to actually install without a user.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **old** "qt-unified-online-installer", where you still could
skip the login, to install a **newer** Qt version!
The latest installer version, where this is possible (as far as I know) is the version 2.0.5-2.

The old installer for Linux can still be downloaded from here:

https://download.qt.io/archive/online_installers/2.0/

Unfortunately, Qt.io, in their wisdom, decided to remove the Windows and MacOS online installers from their download mirrors, but at least a slightly older version for Windows can still be found via Google, search for "qt-unified-windows-x86-2.0.2-online.exe".
Here's a link for direct download that I've found (06/2023), but I didn't test it on Windows!

https://qt-creator.software.informer.com/download/?caeae88

If anybody knows where to get the old 2.0 MacOS online installer, please let me know...

### Example for Linux:

Now run the installer, skip the login, and when you are on the "Welcome" page, press "Settings" and go to the "Repositories" tab.
Disable all "Default repositories" and select "User defined repositories"
(must be selected!!).
Then press the "Add" button to add your own Qt repositories, depending
on what version you want to install, e.g. for Qt 5.15.2 on Linux, add these
five Linux repositories:

```
https://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/linux_x64/desktop/qt5_5152
https://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/linux_x64/desktop/qt5_5152_src_doc_examples
https://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/linux_x64/desktop/tools_generic
https://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/linux_x64/desktop/tools_qtcreator
https://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/linux_x64/desktop/licenses
```

Then press "OK", repeat skipping the login page and press "Next", now the installer should load all data needed to install the newer Qt version, and you are able to select what package you want to install. :-)

### Other versions and systems:

(or: how to get those repositories URLs)

If you want to install another Qt version, and/or a version for ***your*** OS, just look up here:

https://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/

... select the folder with your OS, and go into the "desktop" subfolder!

In here, search for the folder pair that has your wanted version (e.g. Qt 5.12.11 = "qt5_51211" and "qt5_51211_src_doc_examples"), and replace the first two repository URLs from the example above with those two (right click > copy link).
Then search for the corresponding folders/links of the other three needed repositories of your OS ("tools_generic", "tools_qtcreator" and "licenses").

*Tested this on Debian Linux 12 x64, with latest Qt5 and Qt6 repositories.*

Have fun! :-D

Answer (score 0):

There's another **VERY SIMPLE** way that is:

To install brew if your on Mac or Linux.
Then when it finishes downloading, write this command:

`brew install qt`.

It'll take some time tho.